# X11 Forwarding over ssh - Could not find ':' in DISPLAY: 1

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, xorg, x11-forwarding

I'm trying to connect from my mac (Xquartz installed) to a ubuntu server. I use the `-Y` option with ssh. When I ssh to the server and run any graphical application for example xclock, I get the following error

```
$xclock
Could not find ':' in DISPLAY: 1
Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

X11 forwarding is set in sshd_config

```
$ grep -i X11Forward /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# Setting X11Forwarding to "yes" permits encrypted X connections.
X11Forwarding yes
```

and,

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
```

Can someone help me in this regard.

Answer (score 4):

I'll give a generic answer here, because other people might be struggling to setup X forwarding on a Mac here. I think in your specific case, try to run ssh from XQuarts instead of running it from the terminal. Also make sure you have XForwarding set on the *server*side and restart sshd after adjusting it.

Prerequisites to run X applications on OS-X:

- You need to have [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/) installed on the client side (check that it's working for your account by running XQuarts and starting a local terminal)
- You need to allow XForwarding on your server. Set the X11Forwarding option (most commonly found in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`): `X11Forwarding yes` (don't forget to restart the ssh server after editing the sshd_config file).
- Your sshd server should be running on the server side.
- Your firewall (on both ends) should allow for traffic over port 22.

Running X over ssh:

1. Start a XQuartz terminal by starting XQuartz and pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>
2. In the terminal type: `ssh -X [username]@[servername]` (you can also use `-Y` instead of `-X`)
3. You should be logged in to your server. Try `xeyes` for example to have X look back at you.

Troubleshooting:

- "Connection refused": check your firewall settings (on both ends) and check if the ssh server (sshd) is running on the receiving side.
- $DISPLAY errors: ssh should be taking care of setting the $DISPLAY variable. If your are running from XQuartz, this means that (for one reason or another) ssh wasn't able to setup a Xforwarded session. Check any errors in your log files (particulary on the server side) and try ssh with verbose output `-v` or even `-vv` or `-vvv` and look for clues). Don't tamper with the $DISPLAY setting yourself, because it's the *effect* of ssh not being able to establish a tunnel, not the *cause*.

Comment: Thanks ! In my case, I did not logout and login for the X to take effect and because of which it was failing.